# Are too many listeners gargling up my textfields?

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm creating a program that translates across three data types, decimal, hex, and binary. I've accomplished this using a listener for both dec and hex, but now when I create the third listener for bin, it spews random numbers in any textfield I type in. Very weird, I'm wondering if there is some kind of listening conflict involved, I've manipulated variables but the same still seems to happen.

Here is my whole code because I believe you may need to enter it into your respective IDE.

```
    package application;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Elias16_5 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane paneForVBoxes = new GridPane();
            paneForVBoxes.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            paneForVBoxes.setVgap(10);
            paneForVBoxes.setHgap(10);

            VBox units = new VBox(12);
            units.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            Label lbDec = new Label("Decimal");
            Label lbHex = new Label("Hex");
            Label lbBin = new Label("Binary");
            units.getChildren().addAll(lbDec, lbHex, lbBin);


            VBox textFields = new VBox(5);
            TextField tfDec = new TextField();
                tfDec.setPrefColumnCount(19);
                tfDec.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            TextField tfHex = new TextField();
                tfHex.setPrefColumnCount(19);
                tfHex.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            TextField tfBin = new TextField();
                tfBin.setPrefColumnCount(19);
                tfBin.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

            textFields.getChildren().addAll(tfDec, tfHex, tfBin);

            paneForVBoxes.add(units, 0, 0);
            paneForVBoxes.add(textFields, 1, 0);

            //Describes conversions for tfDec
            tfDec.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                 if (!newValue.isEmpty()) {
                     tfHex.setText(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(newValue)));
                     tfBin.setText(Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong(newValue)));
                 } else {
                     tfDec.setText("");
                     tfHex.setText("");
                     tfBin.setText("");
                 }
            });

            //Describes conversions for tfHex
            tfHex.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                 if (!newValue.isEmpty()) {
                     tfDec.setText(Long.toString(Long.parseLong(newValue, 16)));
                     tfBin.setText(Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong(newValue, 8)));
                 } else {
                     tfDec.setText("");
                     tfHex.setText("");
                     tfBin.setText("");
                 }
            });

            //Describes conversions for tfBin
////////////This is my trouble area/////////////////////
            tfBin.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                 if (!newValue.isEmpty()) {
                     tfDec.setText(Long.toString(Long.parseLong(newValue)));
                     tfHex.setText(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(newValue)));
                 } else {
                     tfDec.setText("");
                     tfHex.setText("");
                     tfBin.setText("");
                 }
            });







            Scene scene = new Scene(paneForVBoxes, 300, 100);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Data Conversion");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your `tfHex` listener changing the text of `tdDec` to the value parsed base 16, but `tfBin` to the value parsed base 8? Why is your `tfBin` value parsed without a base?

Comment: That's how it was after tinkering with it, let me double check the first part though

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the concept of the Long.parseLong(value, radix); as I have never used it before. The answer to this is to set each listener to translate to the base you're looking for.

For example: 
The radix of each listener's translation statements need to have the base of the data type you're translating too. So both radixes inside of the tfDec listener should be 10 as shown below.

The same should be applied for the Hex listener's statements, but instead of radixes of 10, use radixes of 16; 2 for the Binary lisener's statements.

```
tfDec.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
             if (!newValue.isEmpty()) {
                 tfHex.setText(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(newValue, 10)));
                 tfBin.setText(Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong(newValue, 10)));
             } else {
                 tfDec.setText("");
                 tfHex.setText("");
                 tfBin.setText("");
             }
        });
```

Hopefully other's find this information useful!

Comment: As a side note, the radix for octal would also be 8. Why I had one of my radixes as 8 to begin with, honestly I cannot tell you.